# Quais os cuidados devo tomar ao criar tabelas com relacionamento 1:1?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6, entidade-relacionamento

Basicamente estou na dúvida sobre quando eu devo usar relacionamento 1:1 ou uma tabela grande.

No meu caso eu teria o objeto

```
public class Person(){
  public Guid Id {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public string Cnpj {get;set;}
  public PersonAdress Adress {get;set;}
}
```

e depois eu teria o objeto

```
public class PersonAdress (){
  public Guid PersonAdressId {get;set;}
  public stirng Enderedo {get;set;}

  public virtual Person Person {get;set;}
}
```

Esta é realmente uma boa pratica?

Ou seria melhor eu ter uma unica entidade

```
public class Person(){
  public Guid Id {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public string Cnpj {get;set;}
  public string Endereço {get;set;}
}
```

É claro que fiz uma versão resumida de mais objetos, eles teriam mais campos e mais relacionamentos 1:1.

Fiz alguns testes de desempenho no `SQLServer` e houve uma diferença muito pequena, em um universo de 20.000 registros.

Porem como eu tenho conhecimento do **DBA**, fico preoculpado.

Comment: Sim, é uma boa prática separar as entidades, e seu exemplo está certo do ponto de visto de como relacionar

Comment: @RicardoPontual muito obrigado!

Comment: Sim! Essa é uma boa prática sim. Inclusive, imagine que, as pessoas se mudam. Se você quiser manter um histórico, desta forma fica mais fácil de alterar mais para frente ne...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tentar modelar tabelas menores sem duvidas é uma boa prática, para isso existe os níveis de normalização de banco de dados para te guiar nesse processo. O seu teste não tem resultados tão perceptíveis porque é um exemplo pequeno (20mil registros para um SQL Server é praticamente nada), o problema vai escalar junto com o tamanho do seu projeto, tanto no banco de dados quanto no seu back-end devido ao ORM.

No contexto do banco de dados, normalizar serve para diminuir a redundância e duplicidade de informação dentro do banco de dados. Vejo muita gente falando que dividir demais causa a necessidade de fazer muito JOINS, mas vale lembrar que o join é um dos conceitos básicos do banco relacional, sendo uma operação muito bem refinada e performatica.

No contexto de classe, um objeto grande fica, normalmente, muito mais tempo na memória e sobrevive a inspeções do Garbage Collector, se torna um objeto de gen2. O problema com esse tipo de objeto é que é necessário fazer um FullGC para fazer a limpeza dele, que é bastante custoso para a performance.

Comment: muito obrigado por sua resposta, muito esclarecedora, tenho muita preocupação com o desempenho de minhas aplicações.